# How do I track how many users clicked on a specific button in my website without using Javascript?

Tags: html, css, statistics, buttonclick

How do I track how many users clicked on a specific button in my website without using Javascript? 
P.S: My website is solely made in HTML and CSS and has no backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shorteners. This will only work if your buttons are links. Using shorteners like goo.gl you'll get statistics about how many people clicked the link.

Comment: Thanks! That worked well !

Answer (score 0):

No you can't CSS has Made only to style your page and couldn't track the data and same for html.